# How to use key in the sort function in this situation (Python)?

Tags: python, list, sorting, tuples, key

I have a list like this:

```
l=[('a',2),('d',0),('c',1),('b',4)]
```

Now I want to sort it, but by the number, not by the word. If I just use `l.sort()` it just sorts by alphabetically. My desired output should be sth like (d,0)(c,1)(a,2)(b,4)

I tried `l.sort(key = l[0][1])` but it won't work too (l[0][1] actually refer to number 2, which is the second value)

Comment: The `key` argument expects a callable, i.e. a function that can be applied to every element in `l` in order to determine its rank compared to other elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass a `lambda` as the `key` that does the right thing:

```
>>> l = [("a", 2), ("d", 0), ("c", 1), ("b", 4)]
>>> l.sort(key=lambda val: val[1])
>>> l
[("d", 0), ("c", 1), ("a", 2), ("b", 4)]
```

Comment: Of course you could also pass `operator.itemgetter(1)` or `def get_1(val): return val[1]`, does not have to be a lambda.

Comment: Thank you. I saw people use this lamda thing in some StackOverflow posts before but I didn't understand it. I'm doing some research on this thing right now. Still, may I ask that after "key", it must be a function, right?

Comment: A *callable*, not necessarily a function. `operator.itemgetter` is a class whose instances are callable. For example, `itemgetter(1)(x)` is equivalent to `(lambda y: y[1])(x)`.

Comment: @chepner but at OP's level it may be less confusing to call everything that's callable a function. At least in this context.

Comment: I don't think it's ever too early to emphasize the distinction between functions and callables (or the fact that a lambda expression defines a function, rather than being something special).

Comment: Every time you instantiate a class, you're using a callable that is not a function.